# chat between server and a client in different computers connected to the same wifi using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, networking, wifi, send

iam facing some problems as i was working to extend a simple chat program over the wifi.
Ive named the two programs running on different systems as client and server thought they don't perform their typical functions.
the message sent by the client is correctly displayed by the server program but once the server sends the message it is not received by the client program.Ive checked the IP and everything is fine. both the client and server codes are also similar the only difference is in who sends the message first(client according to my program) .
I need help with this as soon as possible.
thanks in advance.

this is my client program

```
from socket import *
import sys
import time
TO_ADDR=('192.168.1.101',8135)
hostname=gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')
LOCAL_ADDR=(hostname,8138)
MSG_LEN=1000 
fd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
fd.bind(LOCAL_ADDR)
s=('',)
msg=''
def recv():
    s=fd.recvfrom(MSG_LEN)
    print '\n',s[0]
    print '\n'
    return s[0]
def send(msg):
    fd.connect(('192.168.1.101',8135))
    fd.sendto(msg,TO_ADDR)

while msg!='stop' or s!='stop':
    print '\n'
    msg=raw_input('Enter your message:')
    send(msg)
    s=recv()
    print '\n',s[0]
```

this is my server program

```
from socket import *
s=('',)
msg=''
TO_ADDR=('198.168.1.103',8138)
hostname=gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')
LOCAL_ADDR=(hostname,8135)
MSG_LEN=1000
fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
fd.bind(LOCAL_ADDR)

def recv():
s=fd.recvfrom(MSG_LEN)
print '\n',s[0]
print '\n'
return s[0]
def send(msg):
fd.connect(('198.168.1.103',8138))
fd.sendto(msg,TO_ADDR)
fd.close()


while s[0]!='stop' or msg!='stop':
s=recv()
msg=raw_input('Enter your message:')
send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP (*you are using `SOCK_DGRAM`*) is a stateless protocol. You cannot therefore "connect" to the client from the server as you are trying to do in your code.

See: [UDP Communication](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication)

You have to do something like this:

```
data, addr = fd.recvfrom(1024)
fd.sendto(data, addr)
```

You could change your `recv()` function to:

```
def recv():
    data, addr = fd.recvfrom(MSG_LEN)
    print '\n',s[0]
    print '\n'
    return data, addr
```

And your `send()` function to:

```
def send(msg, addr):
    fd.sendto(msg, addr)
```

And the last part of your code to:

```
while s[0]!='stop' or msg!='stop':
    data, addr = recv()
    msg = raw_input('Enter your message:')
    send(msg, addr)
```

See:

- [socket.recvfrom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom)
- [socket.sendto](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto)